# How do I keep the ADF Web Activity from sending 'Expect=100-continue' in the header

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline that includes a Web activity. The Web activity sends a request to an Azure Function App. ADF automatically adds an 'Expect' request header. The function app is not designed to handle the 'Expect' request header and subsequently returns an internal failure message (code 500).

I wrote another function app that logs the header values to prove that ADF is adding the 'Expect' request header even for simple requests where the content-type=text/plain and the body="test".

How do I tell ADF not to send the 'Expect' request header?

Comment: Is the answer provided by SwethaKandikonda-MT was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.